# How to get many values from a single JSON column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In my DB, I currently have a table that goes like this:

| order_id | country | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Germany | {"selectedProducts": [{"product": {"size": 2.5, "id": 72}, "quantity": 1},{"product": {"size": 3, "id": 25}, "quantity": 1}]} |
| 2 | Germany | {"selectedProducts": [{"product": {"size": 4, "id": 72}, "quantity": 1},{"product": {"size": 3, "id": 36}, "quantity": 1}]} |
| 3 | Italy | {"selectedProducts": [{"product": {"size": 2.5, "id": 72}, "quantity": 1}]} |

And I've been trying to come up with a SELECT sql query that would allow me to fetch the products' **id** to be able to study its popularity by country and such, but I haven't been successful at all doing so.

The **data** column can hold an indeterminate number of products, too.
Care to help? I've already tried using the -> and ->> operators in *PostgreSQL* to no avail, but it might have been me not using them properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [json_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to extract all the json array elements. Example:

```
SELECT
  id, country, json_array_elements(inventory->'selectedProducts')
FROM 
  products
```

To try: [db<>fidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=099d2b500963bc2b5e47ffbe6e2326cb)

After that you are left with products and can use -> or ->> operators to extract a single attribute by its name or use json_each to extract all key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I can keep going with this DB's analysis :D